# Advance Excel chart, scatter chart with multiple axis value with time lapse

Tags: excel, charts, powerbi, powerview, timelapse

I have 7 different measurement points on which is temperature measured for every hour (timestamp). Like these pic down.

[image: 7 measurement points]

I want graph similar like these.

[image: GIF, these is what i want]

Data table:

```
timestamp               m1_temp m1_dist m2_dist m2_temp
Mar 9, 2017 12:00:00 AM 51.72   20.00   10.00   41.72
Mar 9, 2017 1:00:00 AM  48.73   20.00   10.00   38.73
Mar 9, 2017 2:00:00 AM  43.51   20.00   10.00   33.51
```

I get:
[image]

So problem is now:
I need to pick timestamp range (button or just calendar with time) and see animation (not real animation, it would look like that because data ranges would change for example every 2 seconds) on chart trough that time. It would be great to see chart title as timestamp.
Maybe connect points with line, it would be more visible to the viewer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Lots of things mentioned in your post. Can you clarify exactly what you're asking and show what your data table looks like?

Comment: Thank Alexis, I edited question

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I don't think it's possible to have timelapse animation in Power BI visuals.

There is an idea related to this that you can vote on though:
[Animation for ALL!](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/7567137-animation-for-all)

Without animation, there are a couple possible ways to attempt a similar thing. Either use a slicer for time or else show all times at once.

[image: Timelapse]

To do this, your data will need to be formatted a bit differently like this:

[image: Data Shape]

Comment: In power BI you can do animation but only for scatter chart and very primitive. I will try to do it with macro, change every second range for chart and I hope it will look good.